# BibLaTeX langid with autolang=hyphen makes csquotes use localized quotation marks

Tags: biblatex, babel, hyphenation, csquotes

### `autolang=hyphen`:

> Enclose the entry in a `hyphenrules` environment. This will load hyphenation patterns for the language specified in the `hyphenation`
> field of the entry, if available.
> (`biblatex` manual, section 3.1.1)

This seems like it should only affect hyphenation, not other language settings. Is this the case?

### `langid`:

> The language id of the bibliography entry. The alias `hyphenation` is provided for backwards compatibility.
> (`biblatex` manual, section 2.2.3)‏

### `autostyle=true`:

> continuously adapts the quote style to the current document language
> (`csquotes` manual, section 2.1)‏

Ideally, combining these would result in only the hyphenation rules changing for bibliography entries. Instead, it also results in the quotation marks changing to the `langid` value. Why does this happen and can it be worked around?

> ### Literatur
>
> [1] Hannah Müller. **„Wehklagen“**. In: *Einige Buch*. Hrsg. von Tobias Schmidt. Ein Verlag, 2017.
>
> [2] Hannah Müller. **„Zitate“**. In: *Kühle Zeitschrift* 17.4 (2031).
>
> [3] Jane Smith. **‘Lamentations’**. In: *Some book*. Hrsg. von Steven Smith. A Publisher, 1917.
>
> [4] Jane Smith. **‘Quotations’**. In: *Cool Journal* 13.7 (2019).

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[british,german]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}
\usepackage[autolang=hyphen]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{wehklagen,
  author = {Müller, Hannah}, editor = {Schmidt, Tobias},
  title = {Wehklagen},       booktitle = {Einige Buch},
  year = {2017},             publisher = {Ein~Verlag},
  langid = {german},
}
@article{zitate,
  author = {Müller, Hannah}, title = {Zitate},
  year = {2031},             journal = {Kühle Zeitschrift},
  volume = {17},             number = {4},
  langid = {german},
}
@incollection{lamentations,
  author = {Smith, Jane},    editor = {Smith, Steven},
  title = {Lamentations},    booktitle = {Some book},
  year = {1917},             publisher = {A~Publisher},
  langid = {british},
}
@article{quotations,
  author = {Smith, Jane},    title = {Quotations},
  year = {2019},             journal = {Cool Journal},
  volume = {13},             number = {7},
  langid = {british},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: `csquotes` already changes the quoting style in `hyphenrules`, unfortunately I did not find a reference in the `csquotes` manual that states which environments/commands exactly cause the quotation marks to change.

Comment: I might be missing what you mean, but won't `\usepackage[style=british]{csqutoes}` give you what you want? That way quote style is always british and (I think) the hyphenations used will be german when `langid={german}`. This seems to be confirmed if I put `\showhyphens{Wehklagen}` into the `title` field and mess with the `langid` field of that entry, anyway.

Comment: The problem is that `csquotes` uses `\langname` to switch the quote style. And `\langname` is also changed in  `hyphenrules`, even though the `babel` documentation says it should not.

Comment: Oh! I see, the question suggests that it *shouldn't* change with `autostyle=true` in this case. But presumably the OP might still want to use `\foreignquote` (or some variant) elsewhere in the document with auto styling quote marks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`csquotes` uses the command `\languagename` provided by `babel` to find out about the current language.

Contrary to what the code explanation in the documentation currently claims (p. 102 of the [`babel` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/babel/base/babel.pdf) v. 3.14), the `hyphenrules` environment actually sets `\languagename`.

The `babel` maintainer has confirmed that the explanation is right and the code wrong. The problem will be fixed in the next `babel` release.

In the meantime you can use the following modified version of `hyphenrules` that does not set `\languagename`. It's simply a copy of the original with `\languagename` replaced by `\bbl@hyph@languagename`

```
\makeatletter
\def\hyphenrules#1{%
  \edef\bbl@hyph@languagename{#1}%
  \bbl@fixname\bbl@hyph@languagename
  \bbl@iflanguage\bbl@hyph@languagename{%
    \expandafter\bbl@patterns\expandafter{\bbl@hyph@languagename}%
    \languageshorthands{none}%
    \expandafter\ifx\csname\bbl@hyph@languagename hyphenmins\endcsname\relax
      \set@hyphenmins\tw@\thr@@\relax
    \else
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\set@hyphenmins
      \csname\bbl@hyph@languagename hyphenmins\endcsname\relax
    \fi}}
\let\endhyphenrules\@empty
\makeatother
```

With this redefinition your MWE works as expected

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[british,german]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}
\usepackage[autolang=hyphen]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{wehklagen,
  author = {Müller, Hannah}, editor = {Schmidt, Tobias},
  title = {Wehklagen},       booktitle = {Einige Buch},
  year = {2017},             publisher = {Ein~Verlag},
  langid = {german},
}
@article{zitate,
  author = {Müller, Hannah}, title = {Zitate},
  year = {2031},             journal = {Kühle Zeitschrift},
  volume = {17},             number = {4},
  langid = {german},
}
@incollection{lamentations,
  author = {Smith, Jane},    editor = {Smith, Steven},
  title = {Lamentations},    booktitle = {Some book},
  year = {1917},             publisher = {A~Publisher},
  langid = {british},
}
@article{quotations,
  author = {Smith, Jane},    title = {Quotations},
  year = {2019},             journal = {Cool Journal},
  volume = {13},             number = {7},
  langid = {british},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\makeatletter
\def\hyphenrules#1{%
  \edef\bbl@hyph@languagename{#1}%
  \bbl@fixname\bbl@hyph@languagename
  \bbl@iflanguage\bbl@hyph@languagename{%
    \expandafter\bbl@patterns\expandafter{\bbl@hyph@languagename}%
    \languageshorthands{none}%
    \expandafter\ifx\csname\bbl@hyph@languagename hyphenmins\endcsname\relax
      \set@hyphenmins\tw@\thr@@\relax
    \else
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\set@hyphenmins
      \csname\bbl@hyph@languagename hyphenmins\endcsname\relax
    \fi}}
\let\endhyphenrules\@empty
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if this a `babel` or `csquotes` problem. Anyway, the `csquotes` developer should know about this https://github.com/josephwright/csquotes/issues/17

Comment: The code in `babel` is wrong.  The explanation is correct. I'll fix it in the next release.

Comment: @JavierBezos This is what I hoped. Thank you for having a look at this. I'll update the answer accordingly.

Comment: @JavierBezos is it fixed in babel-3.16 from 2018-01-04?

Comment: @JonasStein it appears that [babel-3.18](https://ctan.org/pkg/babel) has now, in fact, fixed this. (see change log).