# hyphenrules environment no longer works with polyglossia

Tags: hyphenation, polyglossia

After a recent update, the `hyphenrules` environment causes an error when used with `polyglossia`. I've been using it for a few years to specify the hyphenation of certain words by language. Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[variant=american]{english}
\setotherlanguage{german}

\begin{hyphenrules}{german}
\hyphenation{Ü-ber-lief-er-ung}
\end{hyphenrules}

\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

With TeX Live 2016 (fully updated), XeLaTeX typesets this document. With TeX Live 2017 as of today, it fails thus:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...nguageshorthands {none}\bbl@ifunset 
                                                  {\bbl@tempf hyphenmins}{\s...
l.11 \begin{hyphenrules}{german}
```

Am I doing something wrong? When I search for information on `hyphenrules`, everything I can find talks about `babel`. Should the language for `\hyphenation` be specified in another way with `polyglossia`?

Or is this a `polyglossia` bug? If so, that would make three that affect my document, and it has been a relatively long time since the last release. I might consider converting my long document to `babel`.

Comment: Did the example work a few days ago with TeX live 2017? It could have to do with a recent `fontspec` update (some parts of `fontspec` are still loaded, even though the package is commented out), but it could help to narrow down the culprit exactly if we know when the problem started.

Comment: Imho it is a babel bug. It just changed hyphenrules and seems to use an undefined command (with polyglossia) in the new definition.

Comment: I noticed today that it failed, and I last updated TeX Live last week, probably early in the week, so I wouldn't have gotten the 9 Nov. 2017 `fontspec` update, but I did notice that I got a `babel` update (3 Nov. 2017).

Comment: Yup, looks like a `babel` issue. My redefinition from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/396614/35864 works (it was a copy of the code in 3.14 with one command renamed). But the new code in 3.15 is slightly different.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can load babel with the base option to get the core definitions defined:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[base]{babel}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[variant=american]{english}
\setotherlanguage{german}

\begin{hyphenrules}{german}
\hyphenation{Ü-ber-lief-er-ung}
\end{hyphenrules}

\textwidth=3mm
\begin{document}
Überlieferung Überlieferung Überlieferung Überlieferung

\selectlanguage{german}
Überlieferung Überlieferung Überlieferung Überlieferung


\end{document}
```

Comment: With this addition, XeLaTeX will now typeset my full document (as well as the MWE) with TeX Live 2017.

Comment: Does `polyglossia` take the definition of `hyphenrules` from `babel`? And why does it not take the other definitions as well? I noticed that my slight redefinition of 3.14's `hyphenrules` in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/396614/35864 would still work. So it is indeed the use of the new commands `\bbl@ifunset` and friends that is problematic here.

Comment: @moewe: yes, hyphenrules and a few other commands are already defined in the format. But imho it is not good that they use commands which aren't (pre-)defined in switch.def too. I think I will write Javier.