# \hyphenrules does not break words

Tags: hyphenation, polyglossia

Following the code used both [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/213168/9077) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/400994/9077), using `\hyphenrules` should inform [`polyglossia`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/polyglossia) about breaking points within a word. The following code does not break the word in question. Why not? What can I do? I'm using version 1.43 of `polyglossia`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}

\begin{hyphenrules}{english}
\hyphenation{de-ri-va-tio-nal}
\hyphenation{non-de-ri-va-tio-nal}
\end{hyphenrules}

\begin{document}

\parbox{0pt}{\hspace{0pt}non-derivational}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Isn't this the standard 'LaTeX won't hyphenate words already containing a hyphen' issue (cf. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2706/35864)? If you try `nonderivational` you get all the break points you wish for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TeX doesn't hyphenate words that contain a hyphen (precisely the current `\hyphenchar` for the current font).

You can define a macro for this:

```
\newcommand{\hy}{-\nobreak\hspace{0pt}}
```

The `\nobreak` (that is, `\penalty10000`) disallows a break at the `\hspace`, which on the other hand allows hyphenation for the following word part.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}

\makeatletter % babel has `allowhyphens
\providecommand{\allowhyphens}{\ifvmode\else\nobreak\hskip\z@skip\fi}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\hy}{-\allowhyphens}

\begin{document}

\parbox{0pt}{\hspace{0pt}non\hy derivational}

\end{document}
```

Here I use a safer definition, that does nothing if `\allowhyphens` happens to be found in vertical mode. It is essentially the same as in `babel`.

[image]

Note that `de-ri-va-tio-nal` is very wrong for English hyphenation rules.

Comment: I looked up in Bringhurst to find out about hyphenation rules in English, but he doesn't give them. What is wrong about it, by the way?

Comment: In AmEnglish `derivation` hyphenates as `der-i-va-tion`, according to Merriam-Webster. In BrEnglish it should be `de-riv-a-tion`

Answer (score 2):

In German language this is a well known problem, because german language contains a lot of concatenated words, single words divided by `-`. For example: `Baden-Württemberg`.

If you need hyphenation in the single words you need to add **local hyphenations** with `\-`.

In your case change `non-derivational` to `non-de\-ri\-va\-tio\-nal`.

Please see the following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}

\begin{hyphenrules}{english}
\hyphenation{de-ri-va-tio-nal}
\hyphenation{non-de-ri-va-tio-nal}
\end{hyphenrules}

\begin{document}

\parbox{0pt}{\hspace{0pt}non-derivational}

No - in word:
\parbox{0pt}{\hspace{0pt}nonderivational}

With local hyphenations \texttt{\-}:
\parbox{0pt}{\hspace{0pt}non-de\-ri\-va\-tio\-nal}

\end{document}
```

and its result:

[image: resulting pdf]