# Quotation marks based on langid with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, babel, punctuation, languages, csquotes

I use `biblatex` with the `csquotes` and the `babel` package. Sometimes words in titles are set in qoutation marks. Normally I use `\enquote` for quotation marks. I want the style of the quotation marks in the bibliogaphy depent on the `langid` field. How can I achieve that?

**Minimal example**

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english, ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa, autolang=hyphen]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{Maximini2018,
  author    = {Dominik Maximini},
  title     = {Scrum -- Einführung in der Unternehmenspraxis: Von \enquote{starren} Strukturen zu agilen Kulturen},
  year      = {2018},
  publisher = {Springer},
  address   = {Berlin},
  langid    = {ngerman},
}

@Book{SchwaberSutherland2017,
  author    = {Schwaber, Ken and Sutherland, Jeff},
  title     = {The Scrum Guide\textsuperscript{TM}: The \enquote{Definitive} Guide to Scrum: The Rules of the Game},
  year      = {2017},
  langid    = {english},
  url       = {https://www.scrumguides.org/docs/scrumguide/v2017/2017-Scrum-Guide-US.pdf},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

**What I get:**
[image]

**What I want:**
[image]

Comment: Why not just using ``Definite''

Comment: But the rest of the entry should stay in German? I.e. the "Zugriff unter"?

Comment: @moewe yes, as the document language is german

Comment: corrected `landid` to `langid`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In situations like this it might indeed be safer to hard code the quotation marks. Anyway ... it is possible to get `csquotes` to change its quotation marks automatically.

`csquotes` responds to the current language as given in `\languagename`. And the `hyphenation` environment does not set the `\languagename` (any more, see [BibLaTeX langid with autolang=hyphen makes csquotes use localized quotation marks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/396569/35864)). Hence, `\enquote` still uses the quotation marks of the document language in your example. The situation would be different with `autolang=other` since the environment used by that setting changes the `\languagename`. But it will also change the localisation of the bibstrings, so "Zugriff unter" would be translated into English, which might be undesirable.

If you want to tell `csquotes` to use `langid`'s quotation marks within an entry that could be done with

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english, ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa, autolang=hyphen]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\def\blxcsq@resetstyle@langid{%
  \ifnum\csq@reset=\@ne
    \iffieldundef{langid}
      {\let\blxcsq@tempa\languagename}
      {\edef\blxcsq@tempa{\thefield{langid}}}%
    \ifx\csq@currentstyle\blxcsq@tempa
    \else
      \ifcsundef{csq@qstyle@\blxcsq@tempa}
        {\csq@warn@style\blxcsq@tempa
         \csq@setstyle{fallback}}
        {\csq@setstyle{\blxcsq@tempa}}%
      \fi
  \fi}
\AtEveryBibitem{\let\csq@resetstyle\blxcsq@resetstyle@langid}
\makeatletter

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{Maximini2018,
  author    = {Dominik Maximini},
  title     = {Scrum -- Einführung in der Unternehmenspraxis: Von \enquote{starren} Strukturen zu agilen Kulturen},
  year      = {2018},
  publisher = {Springer},
  address   = {Berlin},
  langid    = {ngerman},
}

@Book{SchwaberSutherland2017,
  author    = {Schwaber, Ken and Sutherland, Jeff},
  title     = {The Scrum Guide\textsuperscript{TM}: The \enquote{Definitive} Guide to Scrum: The Rules of the Game},
  year      = {2017},
  langid    = {english},
  url       = {https://www.scrumguides.org/docs/scrumguide/v2017/2017-Scrum-Guide-US.pdf},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{Maximini2018,SchwaberSutherland2017}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: The MWE shows a German entry with German quotation marks in the title and an English entry with English quotation marks.]