# How can I localise quotation marks with Biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, babel, quotation

The default style of quotation marks in the Bibliography provided by `biblatex` is the US/UK style: `“ ”`. However, I would like to have the quotation marks in German style: `„ “`, but maintain my specified language (`slovene`).

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{bibliography.bib}
@article{article,
year = {2020},
number = {2},
author = {Someone Someone},
publisher = {Unknown University Press},
title = {The Title of the Article},
journal = {Studies of Something}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[tmargin=1in,bmargin=1in,lmargin=1in,rmargin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage[slovene]{babel}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,citestyle=numeric-comp]{biblatex}

\setlength{\parindent}{1cm}

\frenchspacing

\bibliography{bibliography}

\begin{document}

\section*{Section}

I want ,,this``, not ``this''. \cite{article}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: For the record UK and US style quotations are not the same. Biblatex defaults to US - not to UK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be done automatically, if you load [`babel`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/babel) (with, e.g., `ngerman`) and [`csquotes`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/csquotes).

That is, remove your `babel` load and then add the following before your `biblatex` package load:

```
\usepackage[english, ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
```

To additionally use this with other languages, lacking `csquotes` localization, simply ensure that the language containing the desired localization is loaded last. As requested in the comments, to also use `slovene`, load `babel` as follows instead, and its following `csquotes` invocation will then work as expected.

```
\usepackage[english, slovene, ngerman]{babel}
```

Alternatively, you can only provide your desired language and simply load `csquotes` as follows, manually specifying the quotation type:

```
\usepackage[slovene]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle=false, style=german]{csquotes}
```

A [related topic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/454718) is also worth looking at.

You can view this working with your MWE [on Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/read/vxwswsggtngx).